# How can an end user check what template a site was created from?

Tags: site-template

Is there a way that an end-user (or site collection administrator) without access to PowerShell or STSADM can check to see what template was used to create a given site on SharePoint 2010?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Actually there is, but it seems to be something of a secret that not many people have noticed. Simply view the HTML source of the page and search for 'g_wsaSiteTemplateId' - this will give you the site template and configuration used to create the site.

So when I look at it on my SP2010 My Site, I see:

```
var g_presenceEnabled = true;
var g_wsaEnabled = false;
var g_wsaLCID = 1033;
**var g_wsaSiteTemplateId = 'SPSPERS#0';**
var g_wsaListTemplateId = null;
```

Comment: It did not work for this website www.britcham.org.sg I want to know the theme name they used in designing the website.